# Question about execution relating to derived columns in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a more conceptual question about what happens during execution rather than anything wrong with the code. I was thinking about this in relation to the exercise here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/submissions/code/214661572

The solution I provided was:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT (SALARY * MONTHS), COUNT(*)
  FROM EMPLOYEE
  GROUP BY (SALARY*MONTHS)
  ORDER BY (SALARY*MONTHS) DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

First, looking at the subquery, we see that we are grouping on the derived column salary*months.
However, something that confuses me is that it was explained to me that the order of execution begins with the from statement, and then proceeds to joins, where, group by, etc.  clauses.

The problem I have was in my mind, I have imagined the from statement as the command which tells SQL what table we are dealing with - so when we invoke from the employee table we have the columns as specified in the exercise link.
However, now the next step is to group by (SALARY * MONTHS)... which is a derived column. But, the derived column does not exist in the table that we specified in the "FROM" statement. So how does SQL know what to group by if the column isn't provided in the original table?

The order of execution explanation I am looking at is here: https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution

Thank you.

Comment: This query can only run in Oracle. I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article from SQLBolt, is not realistic.

The article explains how a naïve database engine would execute a query. It can be helpful as a simplistic approach to understand the basics of a query execution, but if an engine worked that way it would be very slow except for the most simple queries only. Nowadays the engines are much smarter than that.

The key concept that you must understand is that SQL is a *declarative* language, not an *imperative* one. You tell what you need, the engine decides how to produce it.

As a general rule modern databases process the query using the phases listed below:

1. **Caching**: Find if the query was already executed. If found, skip to step #7.
2. **Parsing**: Translate the SQL statement into an internal representation.
3. **Rephrasing**: Simplify the internal representation. All dirty tricks are valid here: for example using the same node for all occurrences of `SALARY * MONTHS`.
4. **Planning/Prunning**: Produce all possible execution plan trees, and prune as soon as possible. Include existing indexes to produce plans.
5. **Cost Assessment**: Determine the cost of a plan. The cost algorithm must be extremely fast (typically an heuristic can do), and somewhat accurate, since it must be computed for all candidate plans.
6. **Optimizing**: Select the *best* plan according to the cost. Update the cache.
7. **Executing**: Execute the plan tree starting from the root node and walk the tree by depth. This is not strictly true due to pipelining.
8. **Node Pipelining or Materializing**: a node can start returning rows as soon as possible to the parent node.
9. **Return Result Set**: Walk back to the parent nodes, until the root node is reached. The root node starts returning data to the client app.

As you see, there's a lot going on behind the scenes. Mind that some engines are much more sophisticated than this (e.g. Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL) since they have smarter shortcuts and have implemented so may dirty tricks. Yep... all is valid as long as the returned result is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Two different things are going on here.

The more important is that what gets executed is a directed acyclic graph of data operations.  It really has (very little) to do with the SQL you write.  The only guarantee is that it produces the results that you specify.

That is, SQL is a *declarative* language, not a *procedural* language.  A query describes the result set.

The second thing that is going on is the scoping of identifiers:  what does a column reference mean?  These are defined in the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN`s have nothing to do with this, because they are just operators (like `+` or `||` except on tables) in the `FROM` clause.

Then, the references can be used in the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `SELECT`, and other clauses.  Column aliases defined in the `SELECT` can really only be used in the `ORDER BY` clause.  Some databases also allow them in the `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses as well but not Oracle.

As for your specific question, there is no requirement in SQL that the `GROUP BY` keys be present in the `SELECT`.  Usually they are, but that is not a requirement.  In fact, there are cases when using dates with string names that they might not be used.  For instance, one could write:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'MON'), count(*)
from t
group by to_char(datecol, 'MON'), extract(month from date)
order by extract(month from date);
```

The month number is functionally equivalent to the month name.  To have it for sorting, you could include it as a `group by` key.

Some people confuse the scoping rules with the order of execution.  That is due to a misunderstanding of how SQL engines actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I just give you my opinion, it is pretty intuitive.

You have the subquery query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
-- init_subquery
(SELECT (SALARY * MONTHS), COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY (SALARY*MONTHS)
ORDER BY (SALARY*MONTHS) DESC)
-- finish_subquery
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

First of all it do the **arithmetic** operation, It produces the result of SALARY*MONTHS. That result is the column for Oracle, It only understand that it has some values in one column...

Like: `SELECT (SALARY * MONTHS), FROM EMPLOYEE`

After this execution it gets the GROUP BY clouse to do the COUNT, because COUNT operation depends if there are any group clause.

And finally it order your table.

I do not want to get any point from your article. Just that is a good question and I am preparing for 1Z0_071 Exam, and it is interesting to me to discuse.